# How do I prove a language is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, proof-techniques

I've done a lot of research on this topic, but still don't feel very confident about it. Let's say the example is:

*For a language L over an Σ, define N(L)={w∈Σ∗: wk∈L for some k∈Σ∗}. Prove that, if L is regular, so is N(L).*

How do I go about proving it?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @jbapple I understand that I need to build a finite automata for this and prove that it works for all and only string of N(L), but I'm not sure how exactly to build it and how it would work

Comment: If you can construct a DFA/NFA for such a language and prove the correctness of the automaton, then you are done. (A DFA can only accept a regular language)

Comment: @BanachTarski yes, I understand that. But how do I construct a DFA/NFA specifically for the given problem? That's where I'm lost. Thank you!!

Comment: @CSstudent It seems that your question is a duplicate of something that someone has already asked before. See if you get your answer there.